# How can I host Blazor

Tags: hosting, blazor

I have a Blazor web site but I have no idea where can I host it. My actual hosting cannot run .net core 3.0.
I've read something about hosting in azure, but I wanna know if there are another options.

Comment: Pop over to Join the chat: https://gitter.im/aspnet/Blazor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily host a server side Blazor application on Azure. If you use Visual Studio, you can simply right-click on the project node and select publish.

I host on the US West region and that runs $9 a month.

See:
[Deploying A Server Side Blazor Application To Azure](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4349/Deploying-A-Server-Side-Blazor-Application-To-Azure.aspx)

Comment: Please don't post answers and pricing like this, as these types of answers can be considered spam (as you're promoting a specific cloud provider), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Product-recommendation is one of the primary reasons this question has already been closed as off-topic.

Comment: Is there a minimum version of dotnetcore requirement for a host?

Comment: If you package and deploy your app as 'self-contained' you don't have to worry about the version of .Net Core on the server. The link I posted has pictures to show the process.